# Finding the highest sums of 2 drop-down lists' values

Tags: javascript

I have two drop-down lists and each option has a different value. How can I find the combinations which have the highest value when summed?

Example: List 1 has values 1,2,3,4, List 2 - 5,6,7,8.

Result: Highest sum is: Eight plus four, second highest is Eight plus Three.

Comment: Highest sum = highest # of first list + highest # of second list

Comment: Why isn't the second highest one 4+7?

Comment: why it has to be 8+4 and 8+3...is it that you just have to add only first array numbers with second array maximum ..because if you take two arrays here it would be 8+7 is maximum sum

Comment: @torazaburo Because all combinations where one value is from one set and one value from the other are included.

Comment: @changed but 4 and 7 **are** from one set each.